# Spring Batch - Skip Record On Process

Tags: spring-batch

I wanted to skip some record on process.

what i have tried is, i have created custom exception and throw the exception when i want to skip the record and its calling the Skip listener onSkipInProcess method.Its working fine.

please find the configuration.

```
 <batch:chunk reader="masterFileItemReader" writer="masterFileWriter" processor="itemProcessor" commit-interval="5000" skip-limit="100000" >
  <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
        <batch:include class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException"/>
        <batch:include class="com.exception.SkipException"/>
  </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
  <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="recordSkipListener"/>
</batch:listeners>
```

But i would like to know is there any other way to skip the record on process?

Regards,
Shankar

Comment: yes we can skip the record on coditional basis.please find code snippet beelow this

Comment: You can always read the docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html), and [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html). You can also find good examples [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are indeed two ways to do this, one like you mention with skip mechanism and the other with returning `null` which will filter out item and not write it. Here is [documentation link - 6.3.2. Filtering records](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html) where it is nicely explained what is difference between two approaches. Also this [blog post](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/03/transactions-in-spring-batch-part-3-skip-and-retry/) explains skip in details and transactions in batch.

When you i.e. parse csv file and you expect 5 items per line but one line holds 6 items that is invalid item, and you can opt out to skip it (by marking reader exception as skippable and defining condition in policy as you gave example). However if each line holds name and your use case is to not write items that start with letter `N` that is better implemented with returning `null` (filtering item) since it is valid item but not according to your business case.

Please note also that if you return `null` number of those items will be in `StepContext` in `getFilterCount()` and if you use skip approach they will be in `getReadSkipCount()`, `getProcessorSkipCount` and `getWriteSkipCount` respectfully.

Comment: Thanks @Nenad for the detailed answer and also when to use null and when to use skip listener.

Comment: Hi Nenad, getFilterCount() method is in StepExecution class, how to get this through java?i would like to take the number of skipped records in the job.

Comment: In my test I am running jobs and saving that job execution and when I want to verify how many are filtered use `jobExecution.getStepExecutions()` which is collection, but I can run through it and find my step execution by name which has method `getFilterCount()`

Answer (score 1):

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "step")
public class XyzItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<ABCInfo , ABCInfo > {

@Override
public ABCInfo process(ABCInfo abcInfo) throws Exception {

    if (abcInfo.getRecordType().equals("H") || extVoterInfo.getRecordType().equals("T"))
        return null;////this is how we skip particular record to persist in database
    else {
        return abcInfo;
    }
}
}
```

Return null will skip the particular record to be persisted in database

Comment: If you need to a regular skipping - that is filter out record based on criteria you can identify use the  return null value to skip records from being written.  
The onSkipInProcess is to be used when you would an exception happens during processing and continue processing but would like to take some action for error record (logging, alerting email)

Comment: Returning `null` won't exactly *skip*... Returning `null` would just *filter*. *Skipping* is used for exception handling. Read the [documentation linked by Nenad](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29048138/1064325).

Comment: @PAA Sorry, I don't recall - It's been some time I went through that issue. But I recommend reading the docs.

Answer (score 0):

when we return null in the process() method, it will filter the record and increase the filter count.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    @Override
    public SomeObject process(SomeObject someObject) throws Exception {
        if (some condition) {
            return null;
        }   
}
```

If We want to skip the record , throw an exception. This will skip the record and increase processSkipCount as well.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    @Override
    public SomeObject process(SomeObject someObject) throws Exception {
        if (some condition) {
            throw new Exception("invalid record");
        }   
}
```

Add this Exception to context file as well.

```
<batch:skippable-exception-classes>
<batch:include class="java.lang.Exception" />
</batch:skippable-exception-classes>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are, as well, another way of not writing (skipping) something. For example, let's say we have this step:

```
        <batch:step id="createCsvStep">
         <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="jdbcCursorItemReader" processor="processor" writer="compositeWriter"
                         commit-interval="#{jobParameters['commit.interval']}" />
         </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>

        <bean id="compositeWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter" scope="step">
         <property name="delegates">
          <list>
            <ref bean="csvFileItemWriter1"/>
            <ref bean="csvFileItemWriter2"/>
          </list>
        </property>
       </bean>
```

Let's assume that first writer will write all the values, but in the same time, second writer will skip some of them. In order to achive this, we could extend our writer(for ex. FlatFileItemWriter), and override it write method like this:

```
    @Override
public void write(List<? extends T> items) throws Exception {
    // ...
    if (itemsPassesCheckingCondition) {
        super.write(items);
    }
}
```