# Spring Batch Read Multi-Record file

Tags: spring-batch

This is my first post in here. I apologies upfront if I am not adhreing to group rules.

Basically I am stuck in a problem related to Spring Batch.

I need to read and process a file with multiple records. Something like below:

```html
HEADER
BATCH
CUST
TRANS
CUST
OPT
TRANS
CUST
OPT
TRANS
CUST
OPT
TRANS
CUST
OPT
TRANS
BATCHFOOTER
CUSTFOOTER
TRANFOOTER
```

I just need to read lines start with CUST AND TRANS and skip all others. I have tried with PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper, but if we dont map others then we get exceptions. How can I skip certain rows? Help. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Taran

Answer (score 2):

Use `PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper` to tokenize line and mapping to correct domain bean for CUST and TRANS line.
For lines excepts CUST and TRANS write a generic `FieldSetMapper` used to map from a line to a generic bean (we call it `GenericBeanToSkip`.).
Using a [`ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor.html) process CUST and TRANS transformed beans, but skip `GenericBeanToSkip` returning `null` from `ItemProcessor.process()`.

Comment: `CompositeItemProcessor` is used to 'chain' together multiple `ItemProcessor`s. So the output of CUST `ItemProcessor` will be input for TRANS `ItemProcessor`.

Answer (score 2):

Spring batch have the capability of reading complex files. only thing is we have to write our own readers to process complex files.any file having particular pattern we can read it through spring Batch.

this is file format like your file

```
CUST,Warren,Q,Darrow,8272 4th Street,New York,IL,76091
TRANS,1165965,2011-01-22 00:13:29,51.43
CUST,Ann,V,Gates,9247 Infinite Loop Drive,Hollywood,NE,37612
CUST,Erica,I,Jobs,8875 Farnam Street,Aurora,IL,36314
TRANS,8116369,2011-01-21 20:40:52,-14.83
TRANS,8116369,2011-01-21 15:50:17,-45.45
TRANS,8116369,2011-01-21 16:52:46,-74.6
TRANS,8116369,2011-01-22 13:51:05,48.55
TRANS,8116369,2011-01-21 16:51:59,98.53
```

Custom FileReader

```
    import Java.util.ArrayList;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ParseException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.UnexpectedInputException;
public class CustomerFileReader implements ItemStreamReader<Object> {
private Object curItem = null;
private ItemStreamReader<Object> delegate;
public Object read() throws Exception {
if(curItem == null) {
curItem = (Customer) delegate.read();
}
Customer item = (Customer) curItem;
curItem = null;
if(item != null) {
item.setTransactions(new ArrayList<Transaction>());
while(peek() instanceof Transaction) {
curItem = null;
}
}
return item;
}
public Object peek() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException,
ParseException {
if (curItem == null) {
curItem = delegate.read();
}
return curItem;
}
public void setDelegate(ItemStreamReader<Object> delegate) {
this.delegate = delegate;
}
public void close() throws ItemStreamException {
delegate.close();
}
public void open(ExecutionContext arg0) throws ItemStreamException {
delegate.open(arg0);
}
public void update(ExecutionContext arg0) throws ItemStreamException {
delegate.update(arg0);
}
}
```

Configuration

```
    <beans:bean id="customerFile"
class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResyource" scope="step">
<beans:constructor-arg value="#{jobParameters[customerFile]}"/>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="customerFileReader"
class="com.apress.springbatch.chapter7.CustomerFileReader">
<beans:property name="delegate" ref="trueCustomerFileReader"/>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="trueCustomerFileReader"
class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
<beans:property name="resource" ref="customerFile" />
<beans:property name="lineMapper">
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.
PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper">
<beans:property name="tokenizers">
<beans:map>
<beans:entry key="CUST*" value-ref="customerLineTokenizer"/>
<beans:entry key="TRANS*" value-ref="transactionLineTokenizer"/>
</beans:map>
</beans:property>
<beans:property name="fieldSetMappers">
<beans:map>
<beans:entry key="CUST*" value-ref="customerFieldSetMapper"/>
<beans:entry key="TRANS*" value-ref="transactionFieldSetMapper"/>
</beans:map>
</beans:property>
</beans:bean>
</beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="customerLineTokenizer"
class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.
DelimitedLineTokenizer">
<beans:property name="names" value="prefix,firstName,middleInitial,
lastName,address,city,state,zip"/>
<beans:property name="delimiter" value=","/>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="transactionLineTokenizer"
class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
<beans:property name="names"
value="prefix,accountNumber,transactionDate,amount"/>
<beans:property name="delimiter" value=","/>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="customerFieldSetMapper"
class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.
BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
<beans:property name="prototypeBeanName" value="customer"/>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="transactionFieldSetMapper"
class="com.apress.springbatch.chapter7.TransactionFieldSetMapper"/>
<beans:bean id="customer" class="com.apress.springbatch.chapter7.Customer"
scope="prototype"/>
```

Outpur Writer

```
<beans:bean id="outputFile"
class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResyource" scope="step">
<beans:constructor-arg value="#{jobParameters[outputFile]}"/>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="outputWriter"
class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
<beans:property name="resource" ref="outputFile" />
<beans:property name="lineAggregator">
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.
PassThroughLineAggregator"/>
</beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

output will be

```
Warren Q. Darrow has 1 transactions.
Ann V. Gates has no transactions.
Erica I. Jobs has 5 transactions.
```

CustomerFieldSetMapper

```
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.FieldSetMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FieldSet;
import org.springframework.validation.BindException;
public class CustomerFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<Customer> {
public Customer mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.setAddress(fieldSet.readString("addressNumber") +
" " + fieldSet.readString("street"));
customer.setCity(fieldSet.readString("city"));
customer.setFirstName(fieldSet.readString("firstName"));
customer.setLastName(fieldSet.readString("lastName"));
customer.setMiddleInitial(fieldSet.readString("middleInitial"));
customer.setState(fieldSet.readString("state"));
customer.setZip(fieldSet.readString("zip"));
return customer;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `FlatFileItemReader` to read each line (you posted only one column but I guess you have more info in rows so use `Tokenizer` to separate values per row). Than in `ItemProcessor` check if first token is either `CUST` or `TRANS`, if it is return value to writer and if not return `null` which is spring batch mechanism of filtering items.

You can find explanation on skipping inside spring batch [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29031155/spring-batch-skip-record-on-process/29048138#29048138)