# Spring Batch how to perform Skip or don't consider for writing?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I already went through many links like: [Spring Batch - Skip Record On Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29031155/spring-batch-skip-record-on-process) and simply looking to validate the records in the processor before writing it to the MongoDB.

I've `500` records in the `Oracle DB` and on `162th` record, below code's line-1 satisfy and ***after than no other records are getting considered for writing***, so instead of 500 records, I supposed to get `480` records, `20` records I want to skip because its `EFFECTIVE_DATE` is null which I don't want to consider for writting.

```
public class StudentRowMapper implements RowMapper<Student> {

    @Override
    public Student mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        if(rs.getString("EFFECTIVE_DATE") == null) { //Line-1
            return null;
        }
        else {
            Student Student = new Student();
            Student.setRowIdObject(rs.getInt("PK_ID"));
            .............
            .............
            .............
            .............

            return Student;
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggreed with @Mahmoud, you can also :

1. Add this filter on the query of your mongodb reader : "{ EFFECTIVE_DATE: null }"
2. Return null in your processor

Answer (score 0):

> simply looking to validate the records in the processor before writing it to the MongoDB.

[ValidatingItemProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/validator/ValidatingItemProcessor.html) is what you are looking for. It allows you to validate items and skip them or filter them (see `filter` parameter) before passing them to the writer.